# shell script as an input parameter to pig in Oozie?

Tags: shell, apache-pig, oozie

I have a date format that needs to be changed to system time in milliseconds.
I have written a script for that.
How do i use this output as a parameter to my Pig Script using Oozie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There used to be shell actions in oozie but not anymore. I'd recommend to create a Java action (http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.7_Java_Action)

You can then get the output in oozie context with `<capture-output />` and pass it to the pig script.

Comment: how to pass output as  as a parameter in pig, changes reqd workflow.xml?